# Rails 3 before_save not changing attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I apologize for asking such a noob question, but I'm really confused why this isn't working. I'm creating a reddit clone as a way to teach myself rails. When a new Post is created, I would like to set the upvote and downvote attributes to zero. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It looks like before_save works when I create a new `Post` through my rails server, but it does not work when creating a new `Post` in the console. Why is this?

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :url, :upvotes, :downvotes

  before_save :set_votes_to_zero

  def set_votes_to_zero
    self.upvotes = 0
    self.downvotes = 0
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121223192629) do

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "upvotes"
    t.integer  "downvotes"
  end

end
```

Rails console output when creating a new post

```
irb(main):035:0> Post.create(title: "Facebook", url: "www.facebook.com")
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mINSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "downvotes",
"title", "updated_at", "upvotes", "url") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)←[0m  [["creat
ed_at", Sun, 23 Dec 2012 19:43:37 UTC +00:00], ["downvotes", nil], ["title", "Fa
cebook"], ["updated_at", Sun, 23 Dec 2012 19:43:37 UTC +00:00], ["upvotes", nil]
, ["url", "www.facebook.com"]]
  ←[1m←[35m (124.8ms)←[0m  commit transaction
=> #<Post id: 9, title: "Facebook", url: "www.facebook.com", created_at: "2012-1
2-23 19:43:37", updated_at: "2012-12-23 19:43:37", upvotes: nil, downvotes: nil>
```

Comment: Could it be because you didn't reload (type "reload!") or restart the console after you made the changes?

Comment: You'd better make it via specifying `:default => 0` in your migration.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. All I had to do was restart the console.

Comment: You can also do a `reload!` in your console instead of restarting it ;)